# Как сделать, чтобы при наведении на картинку появлялся блок с отступами?

Tags: html5, css3

https://freehtml5.co/preview/?item=closest-free-html5-bootstrap-template
при наведении на картинку появляется белый блок с текстом и отступами, как мне сделать такое же, в каком направлении двигаться? Заранее огромное спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.b-picture {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 300px;
  margin: 10px auto;
}
.b-picture img {
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
.b-picture:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 5%;
  left: 5%;
  bottom: 5%;
  right: 5%;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
.b-picture-content {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
.b-picture-content-item {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 8%;
}
.b-picture:hover:before,
.b-picture:hover .b-picture-content {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="b-picture">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300">
  <div class="b-picture-content">
    <div class="b-picture-content-item">
      <h3>Title</h3>
      <p>Please support this website by adding us to your whitelist in your ad blocker.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```